# How to plot both Price and Volume in same Chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataframe as mentioned below:

```
Date,Time,Price,Volume
31/01/2019,09:15:00,10691.50,600
31/01/2019,09:15:01,10709.90,13950
31/01/2019,09:15:02,10701.95,9600
31/01/2019,09:15:03,10704.10,3450
31/01/2019,09:15:04,10700.05,2625
31/01/2019,09:15:05,10700.05,2400
31/01/2019,09:15:06,10698.10,3000
31/01/2019,09:15:07,10699.90,5925
31/01/2019,09:15:08,10699.25,5775
31/01/2019,09:15:09,10700.45,5925
31/01/2019,09:15:10,10700.00,4650
31/01/2019,09:15:11,10699.40,8025
31/01/2019,09:15:12,10698.95,5025
31/01/2019,09:15:13,10698.45,1950
31/01/2019,09:15:14,10696.15,3900
31/01/2019,09:15:15,10697.15,2475
31/01/2019,09:15:16,10697.05,4275
31/01/2019,09:15:17,10696.25,3225
31/01/2019,09:15:18,10696.25,3300
```

The data frame contains approx 8000 rows. I want plot both price and volume in same chart. (Volume Range: 0 - 8,00,000)

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to compare price and volume vs time, try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_path_here')
df.plot('Time', ['Price', 'Volume'], secondary_y='Price')
```

[image]

**edit**: x-axis customization

Since you want x-axis customization,try this (this is just a basic example you can follow):

```
# Create a Datetime column while parsing the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('your_path_here', parse_dates= {'Datetime': ['Date', 'Time']})
```

Then you need to create two list, one containing the position on the x-axis and the other one the labels. 
Say you want labels every 5 seconds (your requests at 30 min is possibile but not with the data you provided)

```
positions = [p for p in df.Datetime if p.second in range(0, 60, 5)]
labels = [l.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for l in positions]
```

Then you plot passing the positions and labels lists to `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels`

```
ax = df.plot('Datetime', ['Price', 'Volume'], secondary_y='Price')
ax.set_xticks(positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Comment: Sir, Is it possible to add time at every 30 mins interval in X-Axis

Comment: I edited my answer to address your request. 30 mins interval was not possible since your Date column is confined in 20 sec range